# How to add a Windows Forms Control library directly from Nuget Console?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, controls, nuget-package

I want to add a UI control library into my project from Nuget. When I installed the package, it shows up in the references but not toolbox.

The library I want to install is `AltoControls` in [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AltoControls). Is there a command in Nuget to show the controls on toolbox window?

Comment: It is not very clear to me why the toolbox won't auto-populate.  I'd recommend to right-click it > Add Tab > "AltoControls".  Select the added tab > right-click > Choose Items > Browse and select the DLL in your project's packages folder.  Adds 9 controls, seems to work okay from there.

Comment: I think this is a manual action...

Comment: @Hans I thought that it will be added like a class library when install-package command run for a control library and will be ready to use without any additional operation. But it wasn't like that and I had wondered if any method exists to do that. So it seems it doesn't. Thanks